# SimpleXML not returning attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to display the attributes for all items in an xml file. I have the following xml file:

```
<OPupdate>
    <Version>Testing</Version>
    <VersionNumber>1.0</VersionNumber>
    <GenerationDate>2015-04-24T11:21:53.013</GenerationDate>
    <Product>
        <ProductID>P001</ProductID>
        <ProductAttribute>
            <Attribute ID="1" description="Att1" lang="en-GB" type="string" displaysequence="0">A</Attribute>
            <Attribute ID="2" description="Att2" lang="en-GB" type="string" displaysequence="0">B</Attribute>
            <Attribute ID="3" description="Att3" lang="en-GB" type="string" displaysequence="0">B</Attribute>
        </ProductAttribute>
    </Product>
</OPupdate>
```

And this in php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach( $xml->Product as $product ) {
    foreach ( $product->ProductAttribute as $attribute ) {
        foreach( $attribute->attributes() as $key => $value ) {
            printf( '1<p><strong>%s:</strong> %s</p>', $key, $value );
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not outputting anything. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion here is one of terminology - in the following, "Foo" is an *element*, and "bar" is an *attribute*:

```
<Foo bar="value">content</Foo>
```

In your sample XML, there is an *element* whose name happens to be "Attribute":

```
<Attribute ID="1" description="Att1" lang="en-GB" type="string" displaysequence="0">A</Attribute>
```

It has several *attributes*, such as "ID" and "description", and some content, "A".

So, to access it, you need exactly the same syntax as you used for the other elements, "Product" and "ProductAttribute":

```
foreach ( $attribute->Attribute as $something ) {
     echo (string)$something; // content of the element: 'A'
     echo (string)$something['ID']; // value of the 'ID' attribute: '1'
}
```

Assuming there's always only one "ProductAttribute", as in your example, you can do this, which is a bit more readable:

```
foreach ( $product->ProductAttribute->Attribute as $attribute ) {
     echo (string)$attribute; // A
     echo (string)$attribute['ID']; // 1
}
```

The `attributes()` method you found will allow you to loop over the attributes of the element:

```
freach ( $attribute->attributes() as $key => $value ) {
     echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

That will produce, for the first "Attribute" element, this list of keys and values:

> ID: 1
>   description: Att1
>   lang: en-GB
>   type: string
>   displaysequence: 0

And then a similar list for the other "Attribute" elements.

Blame the imprecision of the English language, and whoever designed this XML structure!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach( $xml->Product as $product ) {
    foreach ( $product->ProductAttribute as $attribute ) {
      echo  $attribute['ID'];
    }
}
```

Actually $attribute will be treated as array or its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Updating comment:
        foreach($pattribute->Attribute  as $attribute ) {
            foreach($attribute->attributes() as $key=>$value)
        you missed one loop,
Thanks for pointing it out.
Old:
attribute is an array
use: foreach( $attribute as $key => $value )
instead of foreach( $attribute->attributes() as $key => $value )

Comment: $attribute is an array of values of the attribute node. Contains A,B,C. Not the actual attributes of each of the nodes.

Comment: my bad, updating the comment, you missed one loop:         foreach($pattribute->Attribute  as $attribute ) {
   foreach($attribute->attributes() as $key=>$value)

Answer (score 0):

It worked with this:

```
foreach( $xml->Product as $product ) {
    foreach ( $product->ProductAttribute as $attribute ) {
        foreach( $attribute->children() as $att) {
            echo $att['description'];
        }
    }
}
```

**edit:**

```
foreach( $xml->Product as $product ) {
    foreach ( $product->ProductAttribute->Attribute as $attribute ) {
        $column = $attribute['description']->__toString(); // the description attribute of the Attribute node
        $value = $attribute->__toString(); // the actual value of the Attribute item
    }
}
```